# Is there a method to filter in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of words : ["sport","technologies", "economie"]

And i have a dataframe :

```
 Text 
 I love sport very much. 
 This is a good technologies
```

I want to create a new column which contain words from list that exist in the current text

Expected output :

```
  Text                    ;  words_match
 I love sport very much. ;  ["sport "]
 This is a good technologies ; ["technologies"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with joined values in list by `|` for regex `or`:

```
L = ["sport","technologies", "economie"]
df['words_match'] = df['Text'].str.findall('|'.join(L))
print (df)
                           Text     words_match
0      I love sport very much.          [sport]
1   This is a good technologies  [technologies]
```

If want case not sensitive values:

```
import re
L = ["sport","technologies", "economie"]
df['words_match'] = df['Text'].str.findall('|'.join(L), flags=re.I)
print (df)
                           Text     words_match
0      I love Sport very much.          [Sport]
1   This is a good technologies  [technologies]
```

Comment: and if i want to apply a set()  to get unique value in list of words match ?

Comment: @AlainPulcini - Then use `df['words_match'] = df['Text'].str.findall('|'.join(L)).apply(set)`